# MongooseJS cannot retrieve data after saving it

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I have a simple ExpressJS app and I'm trying to add user authentication to it using passport, passport-local and passport-local-mongoose, but after I save a user's data on db, mongoose fails to retrieve it, although I can see the data through mongo cli.

At the main express module I have:

```js
// Passport session setup.
var User = require("./models/user");
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

My User model module have:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');


// User Schema
var User = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true}
});


User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

At my routes module, I create a user with the following code:

```js
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {

  var u = req.body.username;
  var p = req.body.password;

  console.log('Creating account for ' + u + ':' + p);
  // Store client on DB
  var usr = new User({ username: u, password: p });
  usr.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render('register', {title: 'Register', error: err.userMessage});
    } else {
      console.log('user: ' + usr.username + " saved.");
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

But when I try to authenticate a user with the passport.authenticate method, mongoose cannot find the user at the db, as I can see on the mongoose logs:

```
Login request @  1422120637815
Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'e@e.com' }) { fields: undefined }
```

But at mongo cli I can see the data:

```
> db.User.find()
{ "username" : "e@e.com", "password" : "123", "_id" : ObjectId("54c3d688fc71a4001db30612"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose is looking for a collection named 'users', but it looks like your data is stored in 'User'. The API for model() is mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit]). so you can force the collection name by adding a third parameter e.g.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User, 'User');
```

EDIT1: 
Try using the built-in register() method in mongoose-local

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {

  var u = req.body.username;
  var p = req.body.password;

  console.log('Creating account for ' + u + ':' + p);
  // Store client on DB
    Account.register(new Account({ username: req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err) {
     if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render('register', {title: 'Register', error: err.userMessage});
     } else {
       passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
         return res.redirect('/dashboard');
       });
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Insertion and retrieve are being done on the same collection, but the retrieve doesn't get any data.

Comment: I think something else is also wrong, because passport-local-mongoose is not salting the password, it is storing in plain text.

Comment: Try using the .register() method that mongoose-local comes with, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after using register(), but I had to change the schema so the password is not a required field.